# Bash script to block mac adresses

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm currently working on designing a linux server that has a bash script that runs every time someone new accesses the website that the server is hosting. What this bash script should do is extracting the new mac address of the client and add that mac address with other text in the before.rules file located in ufw directory.

To just extract the mac addresses from arp i'm using:

`arp -a | grep eth1 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'`

The line of code that needs to be added in before.rules is:

`-A ufw-before-input -m mac --mac-source "the extracted mac address" -j DROP`

So anyone having any idea of how i could do this script?

Comment: I'm confused.  What does this have to do with OS X?

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable to contain your first command (which gives you the MAC address), then output the second line of code with that value in it.

```
#!/bin/bash

ufwdir='SOME/DIRECTORY'
mac=$(arp -a | grep eth1 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}')
echo "-A ufw-before-input -m mac --mac-source \"$mac\" -j DROP" >>$UFWDIR/before.rules
```

Important / disclaimer:

- use >> to write to the file, if you use > it will truncate the file before adding that one single line!
- I have not tested this code, I simply reused your commands from your question.